# Spark SQL Dataframes - using $columnname in where clause of a join works in spark-shell but doesn't compile

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When I am giving the following Spark SQL statement in spark-shell, it is working fine. But the same statement is giving an error at build time when I try to build a jar file with sbt.

`val df3=df1.join(df2).where($"columnname1" === $"columnname2")`

What is reason?

The error I am getting is:  **`value $ is not a member of StringContext`**

I am importing the following. Do I need to import anything else specifically for build?

`import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession`

`import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._`

As of now I changed the line as follows and it builds fine and runs fine as well though.

`val df3=df1.join(df2).where(df1("columnname1") === df2("columnname2"))`

I would like to know why the earlier syntax does not work in a build and what I am missing something in build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forgot the `import` `implicits`, which is already imported in `spark-shell`.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("test")
  .master("local").getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._
```

Doc:

```
  /**
   * Converts $"col name" into a [[Column]].
   *
   * @since 2.0.0
   */
  implicit class StringToColumn(val sc: StringContext) {
    def $(args: Any*): ColumnName = {
      new ColumnName(sc.s(args: _*))
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, this fixed the issue. The sequence of the statements need to be the same i.e. I had to create the SparkSession and then do the import spark.implicits._